# Having trouble with a prolog recursion program

Tags: prolog

So the problem given is as follows

Write a program printfigure() to print out the corresponding part of the following figure for input capital character given by a user. Test your program.

- A
- BB
- CCC
- DDDD
- ... ...
- ZZZ ... ... Z Z

For example, when an input is C the print out will be:

Input a capital character: C
The corresponding figure is as the follows:
A
BB
CCC

---

Anyways, I feel like I have mostly figured this out but the code keeps printing past the given letter. I think it's a problem with my recursion and the base case being skipped. Here is my code so far:

```
 alphabet(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']).

printfigure :- write('Input a capitol character: '),get0(L),
    write('The corresponding figure is as follows: '),nl,
    alphabet(A),member(L,A,0).

member(X,[X|_],S) :- X =:= X, C1 is S+1, abc(X,C1).
member(X,[H|T],S) :- C1 is S+1, abc(H,C1), member(X,T,C1).

abc(_,0) :- nl.
abc(Q,N) :- write(Q), N1 is N-1, abc(Q,N1).
```

Any help is great, i'm just hoping to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: What does `c(X)` represent? You have a fact, `c(0)`, and you query `c(C)`, but there's no predicate (rule) which defines `c(X)`.

Comment: c(C) instantiates 0 to C
edit: i took it out as it seems to not be needed. :P

Comment: `X =:= X` it's pretty useless, it's already matched

Comment: Ah just as it shows, then. I was expecting something more for some reason. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to debug (in any language) it's to separate functionally independent parts.

```
printfigure :- write('Input a capitol character: '),get0(L),
    write('The corresponding figure is as follows: '),nl,
    printfigure(L).
printfigure(L) :-
    alphabet(A),member(L,A,0).
```

and test with the input that (I presume) you think will be fed to your code by get0/1

```
1 ?- printfigure('C').
A
BB
ERROR: =:=/2: Arithmetic: `'C'/0' is not a function
   Exception: (9) so:member('C', ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'|...], 2) ? aabort
```

you can see that

- *when* you're matching elements from alphabet/1, actually you're using them inappropriately.
- *but* you're not matching them: since get0/1 returns a character code (a number), you should change your alphabet to `alphabet([0'A,0'B,0'C...]).` or use a different input predicate, like read/1, or convert the character code to an atom (with atom_codes(A, [C]))

then correct the other error...

Comment: i've tried using read before and am looking again now but it doesn't seem to set the variable right or overwrites the A to the same code.

Comment: If you use SWI-Prolog, you can use get_char/1

Comment: ya i got it to work with atom_codes(A,[C]) as suggested by @CapelliC